# Can't see UITextFields UIButton etc Xcode 6.1.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, xcode6

I created a project (i believe before i update to Xcode 6).  Now when i look at storyboard none of my Obects/Outlets (UITextfields/UILabels/UIButtons) are visible, they are still there and appear when i run in simulator.

Has anyone come across this and have any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you even set up constraints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be you need to need to re-size  the view controller because its default have a universal view so you have to set the size to view-controller for only Iphone.
hope it will work